# How parse json in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

```
{
  "Store123": {
    "2015-05-03": 55,
    "2019-06-09": 39,
    "2018-06-17": 37,
    "2019-06-02": 35,
    "2018-07-01": 36,
    "2015-01-18": 79,
    "2017-02-26": 43,
    "2019-08-04": 38,
    "2017-11-05": 46,
    "2019-02-17": 38,
    "2015-07-19": 59,
    "2015-01-11": 85,
    "2015-02-01": 67
  }
}
```

I have the above JSON data. How do I parse them in POSTGRES so the table would look like below

```
StoreID Dates Score
123 2015-05-03 55
123 2019-06-09 39
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unnest the outer level first to get the storeid, then the inner level:

```
with data(doc) as (
 values ('
  {
    "Store123": {
      "2015-05-03": 55,
      "2019-06-09": 39,
      "2018-06-17": 37,
      "2019-06-02": 35,
      "2018-07-01": 36,
      "2015-01-18": 79,
      "2017-02-26": 43,
      "2019-08-04": 38,
      "2017-11-05": 46,
      "2019-02-17": 38,
      "2015-07-19": 59,
      "2015-01-11": 85,
      "2015-02-01": 67
    }
  }'::jsonb)
)
select sl.storeid, st.dt::date as "date", st.score::int as score
from data d
  cross join lateral jsonb_each(d.doc) as sl(storeid, sd)
  cross join lateral jsonb_each(sl.sd) as st(dt, score)
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention. that's just a snippet of the data, or one row. if i have multiple rows then...?

Comment: each row representing a store and its history data

Comment: @smileyface: that will work with multiple stores as well